# What format should I send data in when using the ~DY command in ZPL2 on a Zebra GK420d for the fastest printing?

Tags: binary, hex, zebra-printers, lzw, zpl-ii

I am trying to speed up the printing of a 4x6 inch png image. I have converted the image to print from ZPL2 on my GK420d printer.

The options specified by the ZPL 2 programming guide are:

- ASCII Hexadecimal
- ZB64
- Binary

Which of these options will print my label the fastest? And if possible, why?

Comment: You can't just try each of the options to see which is faster?

Comment: I sure can..and have done, I was hoping for an answer though so I wouldn't have to research, learn then implement three solutions where only one will be used. I did find that binary data provides the fastest of the three, @KenWhite . I am non the wiser as to why though, I can only guess.